# What's the difference between OpenJDK and Sun Java for the end user?

Tags: java, openjdk

For users running Java application or applets in the browser, what difference does it make running either Sun Java or OpenJDK?

**EDIT**

Oracle will be [retiring the DLJ](http://robilad.livejournal.com/90792.html), and basing the proprietary implementation on OpenJDK. Can we expect similar experience in running Java apps using either OpenJDK or Oracle JDK?

Comment: I believe that's about graphics performance (said to be lower in OpenJDK, Eclipse is said to be faster with Sun JDK), lack (or a replacement of a kind, meaning non-usual, which will raise compatibility issues) of patented (like some graphics, encryption, compression etc algos), 3-rd-party-copyrighted and restricted (like strong encryption) features implementation in OpenJDK. And I will definitely celebrate if upcoming Linux port of Java FX 2.0 will work properly with OpenJDK and be available through the repos.

Comment: Close voters: Please check the date of this question. We are not meant to close questions from 2011, as this type was acceptable then.

Comment: @Zacharee1, frankly, I want to close it because I don't want any of my questions unanswered, and there's no satisfactory answers to be found.

Comment: @Oxwivi this question is technically "answered" according to the system. Any answer with at least 1 upvote qualifies it. But if you want it closed, well there you go.

Answer (score 5):

Suns JDK is much faster for many applications using advanced graphic capabilities (2d and 3d), to the point that some applications are actually not usable using openjdk. See eg:

> If I download the .tar.gz version of SweetHome3D (including the Sun
>   JRE 1.6.0_20), the performance is excellent : moving inside the 3D
>   view is smooth and easy to use If I launch it with Java Web Start (the
>   one that comes with icedtea6-plugin package, that launches it under
>   OpenJDK version 6b18-1.8-4ubuntu3), the 3D view is extremely slow, and
>   unuseable.

http://www.sweethome3d.com/support/forum/viewthread_thread,1658;jsessionid=29F65F93678EF71A067DFEEDDC298B14

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference except for those applications which don't work properly with the OpenJDK.

Comment: Yes, applications *not* working with OpenJDK is the difference. Why does it not work, what's the difference?

Comment: OpenJDK is a re-implementation of Sun's JDK, as any re-implementation of such a large software there are differences, either because of bugs or different decisions regarding certain behaviors. I don't have a link for those bugs, I know they are bring worked, but at this time it is known that are many websites wick work with sun's jdk and not with the openjdk.

Comment: So the obvious next question is: is one better than the other?  And since Sun's JDK is being dropped from the repositories (according to a number of websites, e.g. here: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-jdk-in.html), leaving the OpenJDK available, is it worth it to get and install the Sun JDK?

Comment: "Better" is a subjective term, from a compatibility standpoint Sun's JDK is better, a large number of applications are developed and tested only with Sun's JDK, however if your users can work with openjdk it's always preferable to use the open source version.

Comment: Yes, I've heard of the retirement of DLJ as well. Since Oracle Java is now going to be based on OpenJDK, how will they differ?